# sceneDidLoad Running Twice

Tags: swift, spawn

When I run my program. The code I put into "override func sceneDidLoad()" runs two times.

E.g. 
[image: "testSpawn()" runs twice]

Note: I have no idea why this picture is not uploading, but it shows "spawn" happening twice.

This code should only run once when "sceneDidLoad()" is called.

Here is the code for the "sceneDidLoad" function, and for the "testSpawn()" function (which is the specific one that gave the duplicated printout).

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    var mapTerrain: SKTileMapNode!


    override func sceneDidLoad() {
        cam = SKCameraNode()
        cam.xScale = 1
        cam.yScale = 1
        //do zoom by change in scale in pinch. (E.g. if they start out 5 units apart and end up 15 units apart, zoom by a factor of 3
        self.camera = cam
        self.addChild(cam)
        cam.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
        setupLayers()
        loadSceneNodes()
        setUpUI()
        testSpawn()
        //print("\(self.frame.width), \(self.frame.height)")
    }
     func testSpawn(){
        let RedLegion = legion(texture: textureRedLegion, moveTo: nil, tag: 1, health: 2)
        RedLegion.position = mapTerrain.centerOfTile(atColumn: 0, row: 0)
        RedLegion.team = "Red"
        unitsLayer.addChild(RedLegion)
        legionList.append(RedLegion)
        print("spawn")
    }
}
```

Note: Not all of the code is here (like "setUpLayers()"), if needed I can supply it, I just do not think it is neccessary.

Comment: This was a bug and has been fixed in the iOS 11.0 beta.

Answer (score 0):

Search your whole document for "print("spawn")" just to make sure that is the only time you call the function. Also check for "testSpawn()" to make sure it is only called once. Additionally, instead of relying on this print to count how many times the sceneDidLoad runs, place a print directly within your sceneDidLoad. Finally, check to make sure you are not creating the scene twice.

Comment: The print off is checking to see how many times a unit is test spawned (as I noticed that I was getting a "ghost" of the unity when I moved it, I suspect that this "ghost" is actually a second unit, as I can move it in very certain ways sometimes, which would make sense if they are practically the same unit).

Comment: I don't know how your game works. I would need more code to look at because the code you posted only runs that function once. You must be calling it somewhere else or creating the scene twice.

Answer (score 0):

I've also seen this and submitted a bug report but apple responded saying that it is intended behavior. Apple said that it creates a dummy scene and then creates the actual scene. Before it runs the second time it gets rid of anything done the first time so you shouldn't get any errors from it. The bug is really hard to reproduce, one of my friends working off the same repository that I was but did not experience the bug.

Comment: That would make sense, but does not explain the duplicated unit. Is it possible it does not wipe any entities created in the first dummy scene?

Comment: that's definitely possible, is your node count double what it should be?

Comment: it could also be that the console isn't cleared when scenes are transitioned, for example the console on my project right now reads `view gameover view` because when I transition scenes I print which scene the app is showing

Answer (score 0):

I changed sceneDidLoad to didMoveToView:(SKView *)view if you are looking for a solution to this. Make sure you xcode is up to date.