# SKAction is called twice every time (Swift 3)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

This has been driving me mad. This code:

```
 func nowPrint() {
        print("RUN")
    }


    run(SKAction.repeatForever(
        SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.run(addSpawn), SKAction.run(nowPrint),
            SKAction.wait(forDuration: universalDuration/10)
            ])
    )
    )
```

(where universalDuration = 100) seems to be called twice, because every 10 seconds the console window prints "RUN" twice.

This code is contained in the sceneDidLoad() function, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39590602/6658553

Comment: Yes! Just found that and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42680004/scenedidload-running-twice). I didn't realise that the problem would be with the scene loading. The solution - change sceneDidLoad to didMove(to view).

Answer (score 2):

The solution - change sceneDidLoad to didMove(to view).

Comment: Yes, there is a bug where the scene didLoad method fires twice sometimes depending on the technology you are using (Like GamePlayKit),  avoid using it whenever possible